# Pagination not display when use Jquery Pagination although data display?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, jquery-ui, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I working on asp.net core 5 . i face issue

pagination not display when display all employee data.

all employee display without any issue .

my issue on pagination not display .
when inspect browser it display this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Pagination is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (site.js:4:26)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2:30307)
```

I display data employee by Controller `Employee` action `Index`

my view of action Index

```
   @model TestEmployee.ViewModels.EmployeePageViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>


<link href="~/lib/simplePagination/simplePagination.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 18px;
        background: #f4f4f4;
    }

    .list-wrapper {
        padding: 15px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .list-item {
        border: 1px solid #EEE;
        background: #FFF;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #EEE;
    }

        .list-item h4 {
            color: #FF7182;
            font-size: 18px;
            margin: 0 0 5px;
        }

        .list-item p {
            margin: 0;
        }

    .simple-pagination ul {
        margin: 0 0 20px;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .simple-pagination li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

        .simple-pagination li a,
        .simple-pagination li span {
            color: #666;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            border: 1px solid #EEE;
            background-color: #FFF;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #EEE;
        }

    .simple-pagination .current {
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #FF7182;
        border-color: #FF7182;
    }

    .simple-pagination .prev.current,
    .simple-pagination .next.current {
        background: #e04e60;
    }
</style>

<table class="table">
 
        <tr>
            <th>
              
                EmployeeName
            </th>
            <th>

                EmployeeAdress
            </th>
            <th>
    
                Logo
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
 

        @foreach (var emp in Model.employees)
        {
   
            <tr>
                <td>@emp.EmployeeName</td>
                <td>@emp.EmployeeAdress</td>
                <td>@emp.Logo</td>
            </tr>
}
 
</table>
<ul id="emp-pagination" class="pagination"></ul>

<input asp-for="Pager.NumberOfPages" type="hidden" id="hdnTotalNumberOfPages" value="@Model.Pager.NumberOfPages" />
<input asp-for="Pager.CurrentPage" type="hidden" id="hdnCurrentPage" value="@Model.Pager.CurrentPage" />
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("success")
            var items = $(".list-wrapper .list-item");
            var numItems = items.length;
            var perPage = 5;

            items.slice(perPage).hide();
            $('#emp-pagination').Pagination({

                pages: $('#hdnTotalNumberOfPages').val(),
                currentPage: $('#hdnCurrentPage').val(),
                itemsOnPage: 5,
                cssStyle: 'light-theme',
                onPageClick: function (pageNo) {
                    var url = "/Employee/Index?pageNumber=" + pageNo;
                    window.location.href = url;
                },
                hrefTextSuffix: '',
                selectOnClick: true
            })
        })
    </script>
    }
```

controller Employee action Index

```
 public ActionResult Index(int pageNumber = 1)
        {
            var allemployee = _employee.GetAllEmployee();
            var result = _pageHelper.GetPage(allemployee.AsQueryable(), pageNumber);

            var employeesData = new EmployeePageViewModel
            {
                employees = result.Items,
                Pager = result.Pager
            };

            return View(employeesData);
        }
```

**updated post**

```
console log browser errors
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
index:43 success
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).Pagination is not a function TypeError: $(...).Pagination is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://localhost:44377/Employee/index:44:30)
    at e (https://localhost:44377/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (https://localhost:44377/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:30307) undefined
S.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Pagination is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index:44:30)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2:30307)
simplePagination.css:1
```

**my layout page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - TestEmployee</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
  
</head>



<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">TestEmployee</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2022 - TestEmployee - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/lib/simplePagination/simplePagination.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdn.tutorialjinni.com/simplePagination.js/1.6/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @section Scripts{
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                console.log("success")
                $('#emp-pagination').Pagination({

                    pages: $('#hdnTotalNumberOfPages').val(),
                    currentPage: $('#hdnCurrentPage').val(),
                    itemsOnPage: 5,
                    cssStyle: 'light-theme',
                    onPageClick: function (pageNo) {
                        var url = "/Employee/Index?pageNumber=" + pageNo;
                        window.location.href = url;
                    },
                    hrefTextSuffix: '',
                    selectOnClick: true
                })
            })
        </script>
    }
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you see `Pagination is not a function`, this would suggest that a Library is not loaded properly for your pagination add-in.

Comment: so what i do to load it please

Comment: on action controller data display and pagination but on jquery i don't know what happen

Comment: Check your console. I see `~/lib/simplePagination.js/jquery.simplePagination.js` as your src, make sure that file is readable on the webserver.

Comment: how to know it readbale from console

Comment: Console n Browser will indicate if there are any other Errors loading the items.

Comment: i updated my original post with error browser console

Comment: so what this errors mean'

Comment: so what i do to solve issue

Comment: please can any one help me

Comment: I see `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()` this would indicate that something is not loading properly. It may be a Web Server issue or something else, but it's hard to know from a comment. Would advise you check your Web Server logs for the error. It might be you have the wrong file name or path, which is an easy fix.

Comment: are there are another solution for pagination using jquery

Comment: i can follow another solution for pagination using jquery please if you have please support me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .net 5 MVC project, it already contained jquery inside the project if you created the project by template, and you can find it at `Views.Shared/_Layout.cshtml`

[image]

We can also put `<script src="~/lib/simplePagination.js/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>` just behind the Jquery reference. Please try to put the reference into _layout.cshtml and test if the error message still existed. If still existed, pls surround your JS code with `@section Scripts{ <script></script>}`

All above are based on the error message you found in the browser. And I think you can also use the [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/simplePagination.js/1.4) instead of `~/lib/simplePagination.js/xxx` to make sure the JS file can be accessed.

========================================

I found a [online test sample](https://codepen.io/monkeytempal/pen/pVrwLN) here. And I copied the html content and js into my asp.net core MVC app, I create a new cshtml file, and I paste the html content here. Then I add js code and surround them with @section. By the way, I added the CDN in layout.cshtml. it all worked well in my side except the css.

[image]
[image]
[image]

==========================================================
my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebAppMvcJwt</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/WebAppMvcJwt.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">WebAppMvcJwt</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2022 - WebAppMvcJwt - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.tutorialjinni.com/simplePagination.js/1.6/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    @*<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplePagination.js/1.4/jquery.simplePagination.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

my cshtml:

```
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@{
}

<div class="list-wrapper">
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Iron Man</h4>
        <p>Iron Man is a 2008 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics character of the same name, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Paramount Pictures. It is the first film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). The film was directed by Jon Favreau, with a screenplay by the writing teams of Mark Fergus ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>The Incredible Hulk</h4>
        <p>The Incredible Hulk is a 2008 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics character the Hulk, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Universal Pictures. It is the second film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). The film was directed by Louis Leterrier, with a screenplay by Zak Penn. It stars Edward ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Iron Man 2</h4>
        <p>Iron Man 2 is a 2010 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics character Iron Man, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Paramount Pictures. It is the sequel to 2008's Iron Man, and is the third film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). Directed by Jon Favreau and written by Justin Theroux, the film ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Thor</h4>
        <p>Thor is a 2011 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics character of the same name, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Paramount Pictures. It is the fourth film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). The film was directed by Kenneth Branagh, written by the writing team of Ashley Edward Miller ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Captain America: The First Avenger</h4>
        <p>Captain America: The First Avenger is a 2011 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics character Captain America, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Paramount Pictures. It is the fifth film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). The film was directed by Joe Johnston, written by the writing team of ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>The Avengers</h4>
        <p>Marvel's The Avengers or simply The Avengers, is a 2012 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics superhero team of the same name, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures. It is the sixth film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). The film was written and ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Iron Man 3</h4>
        <p>Iron Man 3 is a 2013 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics character Iron Man, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures. It is the sequel to 2008's Iron Man and 2010's Iron Man 2, and the seventh film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). The film was directed ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Thor: The Dark World</h4>
        <p>Thor: The Dark World is a 2013 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics character Thor, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures. It is the sequel to 2011's Thor and the eighth film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). The film was directed by Alan Taylor, with a ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Captain America: The Winter Soldier</h4>
        <p>Captain America: The Winter Soldier is a 2014 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics character Captain America, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures. It is the sequel to 2011's Captain America: The First Avenger and the ninth film in the Marvel Cinematic ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Guardians of the Galaxy</h4>
        <p>Guardians of the Galaxy is a 2014 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics superhero team of the same name, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures. It is the tenth film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). The film was directed by James Gunn, who wrote the ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Avengers: Age of Ultron</h4>
        <p>Avengers: Age of Ultron is a 2015 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics superhero team the Avengers, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures. It is the sequel to 2012's The Avengers and the eleventh film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). The film was ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Ant-Man</h4>
        <p>Ant-Man is a 2015 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics characters of the same name: Scott Lang and Hank Pym. Produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures, it is the twelfth film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). The film was directed by Peyton Reed, with a ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Captain America: Civil War</h4>
        <p>Captain America: Civil War is a 2016 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics character Captain America, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures. It is the thirteenth film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU), and the sequel to 2011's Captain America: The First ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Doctor Strange</h4>
        <p>Doctor Strange is a 2016 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics character of the same name, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures. It is the fourteenth film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). The film was directed by Scott Derrickson, who wrote it with Jon ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Spider-Man: Homecoming</h4>
        <p>Spider-Man: Homecoming is a 2017 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics character Spider-Man, co-produced by Columbia Pictures and Marvel Studios, and distributed by Sony Pictures Releasing. It is the second Spider-Man film reboot and the sixteenth film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU).</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2</h4>
        <p>Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 is a 2017 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics superhero team Guardians of the Galaxy, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures. It is the sequel to 2014's Guardians of the Galaxy and the fifteenth film in the Marvel Cinematic ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Thor: Ragnarok</h4>
        <p>Thor: Ragnarok is a 2017 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics character Thor, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures. It is the sequel to 2011's Thor and 2013's Thor: The Dark World, and is the seventeenth film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). The film ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Black Panther</h4>
        <p>Black Panther is a 2018 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics character of the same name. Produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures, it is the eighteenth film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). The film is directed by Ryan Coogler, who co-wrote the ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <h4>Avengers: Infinity War</h4>
        <p>Avengers: Infinity War is a 2018 American superhero film based on the Marvel Comics superhero team the Avengers, produced by Marvel Studios and distributed by Walt Disney Studios Motion Pictures. It is the nineteenth film in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU). It is the sequel to 2012's The Avengers and 2015's ...</p>
    </div>
</div>

@*<div id="pagination-container"></div>*@

<ul id="pagination-container"></ul>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var items = $(".list-wrapper .list-item");
        var numItems = items.length;
        var perPage = 4;

        items.slice(perPage).hide();

        $('#pagination-container').pagination({
            pages: 3,
            currentPage: 1,
            //items: numItems,
            itemsOnPage: 4,
            prevText: "&laquo;",
            nextText: "&raquo;",
            onPageClick: function (pageNumber) {
                var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
                var showTo = showFrom + perPage;
                items.hide().slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
            }
        });
        })
    </script>
}

    @*@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("success")
            var items = $(".list-wrapper .list-item");
            var numItems = items.length;
            var perPage = 5;

            items.slice(perPage).hide();
            $('#emp-pagination').Pagination({
                pages: $('#hdnTotalNumberOfPages').val(),
                currentPage: $('#hdnCurrentPage').val(),
                itemsOnPage: 5,
                cssStyle: 'light-theme',
                onPageClick: function (pageNo) {
                    var url = "/Employee/Index?pageNumber=" + pageNo;
                    window.location.href = url;
                },
                hrefTextSuffix: '',
                selectOnClick: true
            })
        })
    </script>
    }*@
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250302/discussion-on-answer-by-tiny-wang-pagination-not-display-when-use-jquery-paginat).